# WooCommerce Class dosen't exist

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

When I try to check if there is **WooCommerce** class is exists inside **my custom plugin** Its return false **but WooCommerce plugins are already installed in my theme.**
I have tried to figure out but I didn't get any satisfying result.

**Can you please explain it to me?**

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

function wpneo_wc_version_check( $version = '3.0' ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        if ( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, $version, ">=" ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: when I try your function in a template file, it returns `TRUE`. where do you use this function ? edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Please add more details to understand.

Comment: I'm trying inside of my custom plugin.

Comment: Isn’t the class `WC`?

Answer (score 0):

For official release installed or not,

```php
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
$plugin_path = trailingslashit( WP_PLUGIN_DIR ) . 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

if (
    in_array( $plugin_path, wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() )
    || in_array( $plugin_path, wp_get_active_network_plugins() )
) {
    // Custom code here. WooCommerce is active, however it has not 
    // necessarily initialized (when that is important, consider
    // using the `woocommerce_init` action).
}
```

You could check the [article](https://woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/#section-1) from the woocommerce that it could be more compatiable.

Answer (score 0):

yes I tried to do similar and this did not work, so try this.

```
if (
    in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', 
     apply_filters( 
      'active_plugins', 
        get_option( 'active_plugins' ) 
     ) 
    ) 
   ) 
{
  echo 'Yes, WooCommerce is enabled';
} 
else 
{
  echo 'WooCommerce is NOT enabled!';
}
```